# How to set Title Bar for multiple tabed view?

Tags: ios, xcode, titlebar

I want to add title named News at the top of this view. I tried       `self.navigationItem.title = @"News"` and    `self.navigationItem.titleView = @"News"` but nothing happened. How can i set it ?

[image: News View]

Comment: does you want nav title for multiple tabViewController VC or navigation controller?

Comment: No not for navigation controller , just a title for the selected tab

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to try this one. In the viewController ViewDidLoad method.

self.title=@"Home";

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated put in this method above code

Comment: Nope , - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.title=@"Home";
}  that didn't work too

Comment: you add this line in above method  [super viewWillAppear:animated];?

Answer (score 0):

You just cant add a title directly at top of the view, either you need to take a uilabel in which you will write your title or you have to embed your each view controller with navigation controller